FFMPeg: Rotate Image on centre of image
Im trying to overlay an image on at a position X,Y of video and then rotate it an arbitrary angle where x,y = 150,100
This however does not work as expected.
Below is the command I'm using.

ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4  -i crown.png -filter_complex
"[1:v]format=rgba,
rotate=-30PI/180:ow='rotw(-30PI/180)':oh='roth(-30*PI/180)'
[rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=150:100" -codec:a copy sample.mp4

Problem is it rotates around a point on the corner instead of middle.
With image example:
Below shows the overlay ( the Dog image) on top of background video ( grid). This is a normal image positioned at 150,100 with 0 degree rotation.

Now rotating it -90 degree should give the below output:** this is the correct expected output**

But its actually giving the output : ** wrong output **

Looks like this is happening because of how FFMPEG handles rotation, while Im expecting it to be rotated around centre, its rotating around one of the corner anchor points. How can I achieve this rotation  I need here?

try: ffmpeg -i graphpaper.mkv -i arrow.png -filter_complex " [1]rotate=PI/6:'hypot(iw,ih)':ow:c=none[r]; [0:v][r]overlay=300-w/2:200-h/2 " out.mp4 where 300 200 center of rotation https://stackoverflow.com/a/75729546/14504785

For preserving the center, we have to adjust the top left coordinate by the movement of the center (the center coordinate moves due to the rotation):
ffmpeg -y -i input_video.mp4 -i crown.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,rotate=-30*PI/180:ow='rotw(-30*PI/180)':oh='roth(-30*PI/180)':c=none[rotate];[0:v][rotate]overlay=150+(600-overlay_w)/2:100+(400-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy sample_fix.mp4
Replace the 600 with the horizontal size of crown.png.
Replace the 400 with the vertical size of crown.png.
Note: The example manually uses the width and height of the input image. We may automate the process using a script that extracts the width and height values to variables (before executing FFmpeg), and use the variables when executing the command.

Example for computing the x, y adjustment with rotation of 90 degrees:
Assume the resolution of crown.png is 600x400.
      600
 -------------
|             |
|      x      | 400
|             |
 -------------
 Center coordinate before rotation:
 cx, cy = [(600-1)/2, (400-1)/2] = [(orig_w-1)/2, (orig_h-1)/2]

    600
 --------
|        | 
|        |
|   x    | 400
|        |
|        |
 --------
Center coordinate after rotation:
cx, cy = [(400-1)/2, (600-1)/2] = [(rot_w-1)/2, (rot_h-1)/2]

For keeping the center, we have to add the following offsets:
delta_cx, delta_cy = [(600-1)/2, (400-1)/2] - [(400-1)/2, (600-1)/2] = [100, -100]

Generally, we have to add the following offsets:
Horizontal offset: (orig_w-rot_w)/2
Vertical offset: (orig_h-rot_h)/2


Testing:
Create sample input crown.png with resolution 600x400 (for testing):
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=600x400:rate=1:duration=1 -update 1 crown.png
Use table.png as "main" image.
Overlay with zero rotation:
ffmpeg -y -i table.png -i crown.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,rotate=0*PI/180:ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':oh='roth(0*PI/180)':c=none[rotate];[0:v][rotate]overlay=150:100" -update 1 sample0.png
Overlay with 30 degrees rotation:
ffmpeg -y -i table.png -i crown.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,rotate=-30*PI/180:ow='rotw(-30*PI/180)':oh='roth(-30*PI/180)':c=none[rotate];[0:v][rotate]overlay=150+(600-overlay_w)/2:100+(400-overlay_h)/2" -update 1 sample30.png

Output:
sample0.png and sample30.png:
 
As we can see, the center position with rotation is at the same position as the center without rotation.

Amazing, works like a charm! Thank you for the detailed explaination!
